# WebRTC: Safari Blocks Video Picture-in-Picture?

Tags: ios, css, safari, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm working on a WebRTC UI that shows the user's video in a small element located in front of the video of the person to whom the user is speaking.

Here's a working codepen:

https://codepen.io/VikR/pen/GXoXRp

**CSS**

```
#pipContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: 250px;
}

#otherCallerVideo  {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#myVideo {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <p id="status">Loading room information...</p>

  <div id="start">
    <button  onclick="start(event)">Start</button><br/>
  </div>

  <div id="pipContainer">
    <video id="otherCallerVideo" playsInline="true" autoPlay></video>
    <video id="myVideo" playsInline="true" autoPlay muted></video>
  </div>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari OS X and IOS, don't seem to permit it. The user's video disappears. I've tried a lot of different ways, using z-index and different kinds of positioning, but I haven't yet found a way to get this to work in Safari.

Is it possible to do this in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. Here's an updated CodePen.

https://codepen.io/VikR/pen/Wgwwoa

The key was putting this `overflow` code in the video container:

```
#pipContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

This was a tough one to track down. Googling "safari z-index video elements" reveals many people having difficulty with this with posts from 2011 to 2018 coming up on the first page of results. Many of the fixes that work in other cases didn't seem to work in this case, possibly because I am overlaying one video element on top of another. The fix that worked was found [here.](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/14#issuecomment-5533973)

Note 1: `overflow: 'hidden'` also works, and has the added benefit of hiding the scrollbars.

Note 2: I have the impression that it may not be possible to change the video dimensions via javascript. In my app I currently set them on the HTML render by reference to `screen.height`.